# Combine two integer columns, keeping NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to combine two integer columns, however, I want to keep the NAs in the third column and not transform them to 0s.

for example,

```
help <- data.frame(score.a = c(NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA),
               score.b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, 4))
```

creates

```
       score.a score.b
1       NA      NA
2       NA      NA
3        2      NA
4        2       4
5       NA       4
6       NA       4
7       NA      NA
8       NA      NA
9       NA       4
10      NA       4
11       2      NA
12      NA       4
```

and I want to end up with a df that looks like

```
   score.a score.b  score.c
1       NA      NA    NA
2       NA      NA    NA
3        2      NA    2
4        2      NA    2
5       NA       4    4
6       NA       4    4
7       NA      NA    NA
8       NA      NA    NA
9       NA       4    4
10      NA       4    4
11       2      NA    2
12      NA       4    4
```

The data does not overlap, but when I use rowSums or transform I end up with 0s in score.c instead of NAs. I attempted to run na.rm = T and na.rm = F to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `pmax` or `pmin` (based on the input data showed)

```
help$score.c <- do.call(pmax, c(help, na.rm=TRUE))
#help$score.c <- do.call(pmin, c(help, na.rm=TRUE))

help
#  score.a score.b score.c
#1       NA      NA      NA
#2       NA      NA      NA
#3        2      NA       2
#4        2      NA       2
#5       NA       4       4
#6       NA       4       4
#7       NA      NA      NA
#8       NA      NA      NA
#9       NA       4       4
#10      NA       4       4
#11       2      NA       2
#12      NA       4       4
```

Or use `row/col` index with `max.col`

```
help$score.c <- help[cbind(1:nrow(help),max.col(!is.na(help)))]
```

If you need to use `rowSums`, we can use the option `na.rm=TRUE` and then replace `0` with `NA` for rows that have both 'NAs'.

```
rowSums(help, na.rm=TRUE)*NA^!rowSums(!is.na(help))
#[1] NA NA  2  2  4  4 NA NA  4  4  2  4
```

Comment: can you explain pmax( ) to this layperson, it looks like it returns all values from the column and does not transform NAs. correct?

Comment: It takes a **p**arallel **max**imum - so for row 3, it takes the max of `2` and `NA` - since `na.rm` is `TRUE`, `NA` values are removed from this comparison. So it then takes the max of `2` on its own, which is of course `2`. When you have `NA` and `NA`, it can't make a decision, so you just get `NA`.

Comment: sorry, i tried right away but it makes you wait... and i forgot to return to it :)